# How can I make the hero image full width, while keeping the contents below it contained, without the scroll bar appearing when viewing it?

Tags: wp-query, images

I'm trying to make the hero image full-width so I chose full-width on the block alignment tab. I'm trying to keep the contents below it contained, so I chose "contained" for the page setting. However, when I view it, the scroll bar appears at the bottom, leaving an odd space on the right side. What am I doing incorrectly? Or What can I do so that the scroll bar won't appear? The container width under "customize" is 1200px. Thank you in advance for your help!
[image]

[image]

[image]